# Why my program displays the output multiple times

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

could someone help me to fix this code. I need my output to display Invalid value input when enter a value equal or lower than zero, However,the output display hundreds of lines. I found some examples adding a (++;)to the value to fix this problem. but, If i use ++ the output displays ( invalid number and a -number multiple times. If i change to -- the output displays invalid value input hundred of times again.

Thanks for your help

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int c0 ;

    cout << " Enter a non negative number greater than 0: ";
    cin >> c0;


    while (c0 != 1)
        //if number is odd  i divide it by 2 i have a remainded of 1
        //if number is even i divide it by 2 i have a remainded of 0

    {

        if (c0 % 2 == 1)

            c0 = (3 * c0) + 1;

         if (c0 <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid value input " ;

        }

        else 
            c0 /= 2;

        cout << c0 << '\n';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, you are displaying the number multiple times because you put `cout << "Invalid value input " ;` inside the loop. If you had put that before the loop it would display only once.

```
cout << " Enter a non negative number greater than 0: ";
cin >> c0;
if (c0 <= 0)
{
        cout << "Invalid value input " ;
}
while (c0 != 1)
{
   ...
}
```

Next thing to think about is what you want to happen when the user inputs an invalid number. Do you want to abort the program? Do you want to ask the user again? At the moment the program will just carry on as if nothing had happened.

Comment: thanks I will pay more attention to  code structure.